# How do you use several request handler in node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, url

I come from tornado, where you have a requestHandler class and you match the query to orient it to the right requestHandler.

How do you do in node.js? Something like that ????

```
http=require ('http');
url=require('url')


function case1(request,response){ ... }

function case2(request,response){ ... }

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
     var q=url.parse(request.url, true).query
     switch(true){
       case /friend/.test(q):
           case1(request,response);
           return;
       case /foes/.test(q):
           case2(request,response);
           return;
     }
}).listen(9999)
```

Comment: you use a framework for that, ie [espress](http://expressjs.com/) or [restify](http://restify.io/)

Comment: Are `friend` and `foes` intended to be URL paths? Or are you wanting to test for the presence of those as query-string parameters?

Comment: yes, they are url path. Soulcheck, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683916/node-js-express-vs-geddy/5683938#5683938 , Raynos said "Frameworks?! Real men use node directly". I've come to hate django, so i don't want to go back there.

Comment: @JulienFr I think Raynos was mostly being facetious with that comment. In the next line, he links to [`npm-www`](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www), the source behind [npmjs.org](https://npmjs.org/), which [uses numerous libraries](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www/blob/v0.2.0/package.json#L7-L42). So, he wasn't suggesting to avoid all libraries, always. He even mentioned that "*NPM is your friend.*" His suggestion is that preference should be with using a few smaller, targeted libraries over frameworks. Though, YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Node.js' [`http.Server`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server), you're on your own for establishing any routing.

And, you're close to this. Though, you'll want to test based on the parsed URL's [`pathname`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url) rather than `query`.

```
var pathname = url.parse(request.url, true).pathname;

switch (true) {
    case /\/friend/.test(pathname):
        case1(request, response);
        break;

    case /\/foes/.test(pathname):
        case1(request, response);
        break;
}
```

You'll probably also want to include testing the [`request.method`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_method).

```
case request.method === 'GET' && /\/friend/.test(pathname):
```

Or, as [soulcheck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642340/soulcheck) mentioned, there are [numerous libraries/framework available](https://npmjs.org/search?q=router) that have an established API for routing, including [express](https://npmjs.org/package/express) and [restify](https://npmjs.org/package/restify).

```
var app = express();

app.get('/friend', case1);
app.get('/foes', case2);
```

Comment: @JulienFr Between "*vanilla*" and using library or between Express and Restify? 1) Node's API is rather low-level in many ways, so "*vanilla*" can take up extra development time to accomplish. For `http.Server`s, I would suggest finding a router you like. 2) [Restify's docs](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) actually include a good summary of the differences to Express: "*Express' use case is targeted at browser applications and contains a lot of functionality, such as templating and rendering, to support that. Restify does not.*"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution: You can compose several handlers into one handler using function composition. Each handler should yield the execution to the next handler, if the `req.url` doesn't matches. The `wrapHandler` can be further extended to consider HTTP methods too.

```
var http = require('http');

var handler1 = function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('/');
    res.end();  
}

var handler2 = function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('/Hello');
    res.end();  
}

var middleware = compose([wrapHandler('/', handler1),
                         wrapHandler('/hello', handler2)]);

http.createServer(middleware).listen(3000);

function wrapHandler(path, cb) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.url === path) {
            cb(req, res);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    };
}

function notFoundHandler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('No Path found');
    res.end();    
};

// adapted from koa-compose
function compose(middleware) {
    return function (req, res){
        let next = function () {
            notFoundHandler.call(this, req, res);
        };

        let i = middleware.length;
        while (i--) {
            let thisMiddleware = middleware[i];
            let nextMiddleware = next;
            next = function () { 
                thisMiddleware.call(this, req, res, nextMiddleware);
            }
        }
        return next();
    }
}
```